# Pass data to a FORM and auto submit it

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

The thing I'm trying to have is a JQuery/JavaScript code that will automatically pass some data from facebook to a form (basically the form doesn't need to be shown). so the first part is ready (the part that pulls the data from facebook).

```
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
      };
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
         if (response.session) {
         FB.api({
         method: "fql.query",
         query: "SELECT name,email FROM user WHERE uid = " + response.session.uid
            }
```

Now i need to insert the name and the email to the inputs with name="name" and name="email" and auto submit the form.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: here is the form:

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >

<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="XXXXXXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="XXXXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="XXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />

<input id="awf_field-22176678" type="text" name="name" class="text" value=""  tabindex="500" />

<input class="text" id="awf_field-22176679" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501"  />

<input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="502" />
<div class="af-clear">

</form>
```

EDIT 2: I need to do something like this just simplified with jQuery:

```
        <?php
        $formcode = '<form method="post" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >

<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="864136470" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="fbu-ppv-mmoney1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="FB_Ultralizer_PPV" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />

<input id="awf_field-22176678" type="text" name="name" class="text" value=""  tabindex="500" />

<input class="text" id="awf_field-22176679" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501"  />

<input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="502" />

</form>
'; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
                                                customar_formcode="$formcode";
                                                customar_formcode=customar_formcode.replace("{email}", user.email);
                                                customar_formcode=customar_formcode.replace("{name}", user.name);
                                                document.getElementById(\'form\').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to fill out a form that exists already in the DOM and then submit it, or are you trying to do a POST to some url without actually presenting any form to a user?

Comment: Well, maybe ill make the DOM as a PHP variable and then parse it somehow? I don't really want to make hidden DIV's and stuff like that.

Comment: It depends on what you need to do, the answer below is the right way to just send a post. If you want to actually redirect the user to that page, and show its response, etc, e.g. simulate an actual action of a user filling a form and clicking "submit", the simplest way is basically to create a form in the DOM, fill it and submit it. You can build it dynamically but there's nothing really wrong with just having a hidden form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery's [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to send the data without the need for the markup for a form and using auto submits:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

**EDIT:**
If you have already got the form setup in the DOM you should just fill it in with JavaScript and submit it with JavaScript

To change the input values use Jquery like so:

```
$('input[name$="name"]').val('value');
```

once all the inputs are set to how you want them you can submit the form using [this](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

if you have the ID form on your form then you can use code like

```
$('#form').submit();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I just added edited the post with the form, I'm a bit confused how can i send all the needed information using jQuery's POST, can you please provide a short example with the form i provided?

Comment: Is the form hidden to the user or does it require user input?

Comment: Thanks for your edit buddy, ill try that asap. And the form is hidden and i would even prefer to make it as a PHP variable so it will not be shown on the source code, is it possible?

Comment: if its a PHP variable it will have to be on the server side and used when the form is posted to the server, So after the  $('#form').submit() from the client side is run. So it wouldn't be needed to be in the HTML markup at all.

Comment: Well i've tried and seems like it doesn't work for me, what do you mean by "So after the $('#form').submit() from the client side is run"? where do i place the variable (before the JS or after it)? how do i access it using JS?

Comment: if you put PHP variables inside the HTML page it will be view able by anyone. you can do things like 'var variable = <?php echo $variable ?>;' This will get the PHP variable into JavaScript but it will be in the HMTL source.

Comment: I'm talking about a variable, not an echo... variable like $hey = "hello" are not visible and I'm just asking if i could access $hey and submit the form from there, or maybe put the form in a different file and access that file with Jqeury? just something to hide the form completly from the page.

Comment: Php is executed ON the server before the file is sent to the client. There would be no way to access php variables from JavaScript directly. If you wanted to hide the form you might need to rethink your implementation, what in the form does the client side need to have to work correctly? what don't you want them to have? do they need to have the bits you don't want them to have?

Comment: well it doesn't really need to be PHP that was only my suggestion ;) maybe i can submit a form that placed on a different html file?

Comment: Anything you want the client to do it will have access to. If you don't want the client to know about it keep it server side. What from the form does how much of it needs to be on the client side?

Comment: I just edited the post with the way i want to do it (found the javascript somewhere on the net, is it possible to do the same with jQuery? If no just write it and ill find a way around, you helped me enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can pass all data of form at once with something like:
var data = $(#formID).serialize();